# Windows 10 doesn't shutdown on Lenovo Yoga Pro 2

Tags: shutdown, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro and since October been using Windows 10 - all fine until last night when MS installed the latest upgrade. All seemingly went fine until today when I tried to shut it down. It has been in "shutting down" for over two hours and I can't turn it off nor restart

Answer (score 0):

You can shut it down by either pressing the power button for longer than 5 seconds or by waiting until the battery drains.

Edit: Microsoft has released a faulty November Update for Windows 10. Maybe it was that that caused the error. The new Version of the 1511 Update should be goood.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was able to restart after that. Any suggestions for fixing this for the future?

Comment: @jackboniecki well, if this worked....  Why not do it Again? As to why, you provided too little detail to answer ! Things like this Happen. Sometime a hard reboot totally destroys the machine,  I personally don't like this answer but accept sometimes it's about luck

Comment: If it worked, please Mark as answered

Comment: @Dave Never had a hard reboot causing more trouble than losing unsaved data. Unless you are flashing a BIOS or a new Firmware nothing real bad should happen.